# Multi posts per pages

Tags: haskell, hakyll

I'm making a website with Hakyll and I would like to gather some posts in the same page. I find somes example on websites such as [dannysu](https://github.com/dannysu/hakyll-blog/blob/master/site.hs) or [EAnalytica](http://www.eanalytica.com/site/), but my code is not working and I don't understand why.

My code compile fine, the `trace` function show that all the posts are loaded, the compilation is successfull but all the webpages supposed to contain 3 posts are empty. Only the text before the loop and the links to the next and previous pages are visible.

[image]

My Hakyll code is the following.

```
toolsPages = do
  pag <- buildPaginateWith grouper "tools/*" makeId
  paginateRules pag $ \pageNum pattern -> trace (show pag) $ do
      route idRoute
      compile $ do
          posts <- recentFirst =<< loadAll pattern
          let paginateCtx = paginateContext pag pageNum
              ctx =
                  constField "title" ("Tools - Page " ++ (show pageNum)) <>
                  listField "tools" (postCtx) (return posts) <>
                  paginateCtx <>
                  defaultContext
          makeItem ""
              >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/outils-pag.html" ctx
              >>= relativizeUrls

grouper ids = (liftM (paginateEvery 3) . sortRecentFirst) ids

makeId pageNum = fromFilePath $ "blog/page/" ++ (show pageNum) ++ "/index.html"

postCtx :: Context String
postCtx =
  dateField "date" "%d / %m / %Y"
  `mappend` bodyField "body"
  `mappend` defaultContext
```

The templates/outils-pag.html template contains the following.

```
some text before the loop
$for(tool)$
some text inside the loop
$date$
$teaser$
$body$
$endfor$

$if(previousPageNum)$
<a href="$previousPageUrl$">previous</a>
$else$
$endif$
&mdash;
$currentPageNum$ of $numPages$
&mdash;
$if(nextPageNum)$
<a href="$nextPageUrl$">next</a>
$else$
$endif$
```

Do you have an idea of what is wrong with my code?
Do you know another example of pagination with Hakyll?

Comment: What is "the generated webpage"? Does it create the paginated files? And what does "show nothing" mean, is each file empty?

Comment: I have added some precisions. The generated pages supposed to show 3 posts are nearly empty. Only the link to the next and previous pages appear.

Comment: Does the `for` loop run and create some whitespaces (empty lines) in the resulting file, or is `tools` itself empty?

Comment: I think the `for` loop is not working because when I put some text in the loop, this text doesn't appear. How can I know if `tools` is empty or not ?

Comment: Yes, putting text inside the loop is enough, it would show for sure. So if `tools` is empty, that suggests `loadAll` doesn't match anything (which is weird given that the paginator seems to know the entries and their number). Do you have a `compile` rule for all of the tool posts?

Comment: I don't know. This code snippet is the only one I use for pagination. What do you mean by `compile rule`?

Comment: Iirc, `loadAll` doesn't find anything that is not already `match`ed by a general rule elsewhere. So if you don't do anything else (like rendering each on its own page) with the `/tools/*` posts that's likely the reason

Comment: It Works ! You where right ! I created a basic compile rule to create standalone pages for tools and the pagination work as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This basic compile rule must be run before pagination :

```
tools = do
  match "tools/*" $ do
    route $ setExtension "html"
    compile $ compiler
      >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/tools.html"    postCtx
      >>= relativizeUrls
```

And then, it Work!

Comment: You don't even need to `route` it - `compile`ing it should be enough (like for templates)